# adding condition to mysql json query

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query like this that go over my mysql records of certain table and gives me jsons out of each record:

```
SELECT json_object(
  'personId', p.id,
  'formalName', p.name,
  'country', p.country)
FROM person p;
```

but I `formalName` can be null, and I wanted to add a condition like

```
if p.name is null 'NoName' else p.name
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap change `p.name` to `case when p.name is null then 'NoName' else p.name end` at the end your query will be:

```
SELECT json_object(
  'personId', p.id,
  'formalName', case when p.name is null then 'NoName' else p.name end,
  'country', p.country)
FROM person p;
```